# Bring back 10 lowest values based on a condition

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I have a table measuring the distance and time via public transport between two postcodes. The postcodes are down column A and also are written in row 1:1 (photo below to explain)

I want to write a formula that says

Match Area name - ie 'Holborn' in the horizontal row, search down column matching 'distance' and return 10 smallest values telling me the distance BUT also bring back the matching store (from column A).

Help very much appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvgT5.png)

I was trying to achieve it with a filter, sort and limit but I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please edit your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
={A2:A, FILTER(B2:Z, B1:Z1="Holborn")}
```